What DeepGram SDK C# object to use when receiving a response?
I am using the DeepGram API alongside the SDK (https://github.com/deepgram/deepgram-dotnet-sdk) to process voice to text.
I have setup a webhook to listen for the incoming transcript e.g.
 public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveTranscription()
 {   
    using var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    var requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        
     // Parse the webhook payload
     var transcript = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XXXXXXXXXX>(requestBody);

My question is, what object from the SDK should I use when deserializing the incoming body? e.g. what should XXXXXXXXXX be in the above code?
I can "Roll my own" but that may not work with any changes moving forward hence the reason for me wanting to use the SDK.
I'm using .NET 6.0 just as an FYI.
